# Using Spring Security principal property in a tag (e.g.<a>)

Tags: jsp, spring-security, el

I am trying to use the user id, stored as a principal property inside the Spring Security Authentication token in a HTML tag such as :

```
<a href="/users/${id}">Profile page</a>
```

I am only aware of two alternatives to use the id from the Spring Security principal object:

1. Use the dedicated taglib's authentication tag (wouldn't work here, as JSP doesn't allow nested tags as far as I know).
2. Use a scriptlet, which I would really like to avoid. If anybody is aware of a an elegant one doing the job, I would be interested anyway.

I would like to be able to use something along the lines of EL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSTL c:set` for this:

```
<c:set var="id"><security:authentication property="username" /></c:set>
<a href="/users/${id}">Profile page</a>
```

Comment: c:set is not needed. we can use <security:authentication property="username" var="id" />